# How to use reorder within ggplot2 for descending total and facet by category

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

My goal is for the Category2 to be faceted, with boy in order, by num_boys, in its own facet and girl in order by num_girls in its own facet.

data frame bg_places

| place | Category2 | total_number | num_boys | num_girls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Greenhouse | boy | 66394 | 66394 | 0 |
| Coffeehouse | boy | 33539 | 33539 | 0 |
| Safe House | boy | 29757 | 29757 | 0 |
| Birthday Party | boy | 23285 | 23285 | 0 |
| Downtown | boy | 21309 | 21309 | 0 |
| Barnyard | boy | 19885 | 19885 | 0 |
| Bungalow | boy | 19421 | 19421 | 0 |
| Bazaar | boy | 16982 | 16982 | 0 |
| Transylvania | boy | 16644 | 16644 | 0 |
| Aquarium | boy | 16596 | 16596 | 0 |
| New Brunswick | boy | 16452 | 16452 | 0 |
| Drugstore | boy | 16338 | 16338 | 0 |
| Landfill | boy | 16173 | 16173 | 0 |
| Suburbia | boy | 16166 | 16166 | 0 |
| Cathouse | boy | 15427 | 15427 | 0 |
| Freeway | boy | 15193 | 15193 | 0 |
| Bathroom | boy | 14818 | 14818 | 0 |
| Hometown | boy | 14789 | 14789 | 0 |
| Rose Garden | boy | 14709 | 14709 | 0 |
| Motel Room | boy | 14272 | 14272 | 0 |
| Bus Station | boy | 13622 | 13622 | 0 |
| Government Agency | boy | 13332 | 13332 | 0 |
| Massachusetts Institute of Technology | boy | 13135 | 13135 | 0 |
| Farmhouse | boy | 13017 | 13017 | 0 |
| Earth | boy | 12996 | 12996 | 0 |
| New Brunswick | girl | 24615 | 0 | 24615 |
| Moon | girl | 23847 | 0 | 23847 |
| Barnyard | girl | 23691 | 0 | 23691 |
| Transylvania | girl | 20982 | 0 | 20982 |
| Vacant Lot | girl | 19289 | 0 | 19289 |
| Dead End | girl | 18970 | 0 | 18970 |
| Cocktail Party | girl | 18816 | 0 | 18816 |
| Butcher Shop | girl | 17757 | 0 | 17757 |
| Coffee Shop | girl | 17120 | 0 | 17120 |
| Police Station | girl | 16752 | 0 | 16752 |
| Suburbia | girl | 16678 | 0 | 16678 |
| Landfill | girl | 16574 | 0 | 16574 |
| Greenhouse | girl | 16352 | 0 | 16352 |
| Bazaar | girl | 16280 | 0 | 16280 |
| Backyard | girl | 16096 | 0 | 16096 |
| Catholic School | girl | 15445 | 0 | 15445 |
| Downtown | girl | 15436 | 0 | 15436 |
| Hired Help | girl | 15246 | 0 | 15246 |
| Earth | girl | 15027 | 0 | 15027 |
| Government Agency | girl | 14720 | 0 | 14720 |
| Grade School | girl | 14550 | 0 | 14550 |
| Safe House | girl | 14550 | 0 | 14550 |
| Amusement Park | girl | 14456 | 0 | 14456 |
| Dining Room | girl | 14364 | 0 | 14364 |
| Chicken Coop | girl | 14236 | 0 | 14236 |

```
bg_places_q <-  bg_places %>%  
             ggplot(aes(x = reorder(place, -total_number), y = total_number)) +    
      geom_col(position = "dodge") +  
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +  
      facet_wrap(~Category2, scales = "free_x")
```

)
[the above code executed on the data frame shown above (bg_places)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dWmn.png)

You can see in the data frame bg_places that New Brunswick is the place with the highest num_girls, but the visualization shows Greenhouse, which is not my goal.

Comment: Does this help? https://juliasilge.com/blog/reorder-within/

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are order correctly, but it is suggested to change the labels.

```
bg_places %>%
         ggplot(aes(x = reorder(-total_number, Category2), y = total_number)) +  
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +  
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  facet_wrap(~Category2, scales = "free_x")
```